# Linking 2 cells in Excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I need to link 2 cells from 2 different excel workbooks. How can I do that? 
Example: Say if `A1` cell of `Book1` and `B2` of `Book2` are linked. If I update A1 cell of `Book1` with `1000`, then `B2` of `Book2` should automatically get updated to `1000`. Any idea how to link the cells in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the standard way: Build the correct formula in excel, look at the parts and build the string in C#. Then assign this string value to the range.formula  property and you are done...

Comment: I tried that. Its working fine in the worksheet which comes when we run VSTO. But later, if I open any other, it is not working. So, was wandering if there are some c# APIs to do it directly. Are you aware of any?

Comment: I am assuming it must be throwing an exception in later case. Can you think of any loophole here?

Comment: What happens, if when you set the cell?
Do the desired text and the generated text look identical?
It would be great if you could provide a sample file and code...

Comment: Oh. Resolved it! was getting HRESULT: 0x800A03EC exception. Found out that I was missing THE `'` in the filename! Thanks @christian for your time.